# Images API Python with google cloud storage

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

Has someone a working example how to serve images dynamically without Blobstore ? Blobstore is deprecated and I would like to use the Images API in order to crop, resize and serve images which are stored in a google cloud bucket.

At the moment I am using cloud-storage in order to serve images but it was not possible to include the Images API. An example url looks like: https://storage.googleapis.com/orbital-views.appspot.com/blabla2.png?Signature=OHLKMc64WzThGSOU3Rv8MMWz919Pjl%2FYs9Nhw4abqVTX04h4aYniC%2B%2FCtMIeh2stA70KJFdKY1YNuwhBWxDQ4CaiXy0Onn3Fy7tkW1kXw0P5EhDhKQQ27ufgUmOkYxOULo65YkfdW7fVoVeruwdTahk3I94ac4Et3Bvs4nXHW4PQqk31dLVKwYLlTkAvUArg3oiaWsAwAZUKWjfYfw9z8i68QrZubDIB8zski%2FAukPgbT5c%2B8eq8BBPbdkcS1YiL9Wz6Yl1y8VCJxM%2BVMg81IIwCfF9qoJk8Cus20PBXrDYyO7sLvLx5Dy%2BfdMxqmi%2BIZZ2JAhfdjM3oZul5cj%2B9%2Bg%3D%3D&GoogleAccessId=orbital-views%40appspot.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1504477278

This url is generated using a signed url approach. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-signed-urls-program

My aim is to serve an image with the Images API Python.
I tried the following methods but without success.

```
url = images.get_serving_url(None,filename=’/gs/xxx.appspot.com/’)

blobstore_filename = '/gs{}'.format(filename)

blob_key = blobstore.create_gs_key(blobstore_filename)

url2 = images.get_serving_url(blob_key)
```

Comment: Blobstore deprecated????

Comment: Here some code to move from blobstore to gcs: https://github.com/voscausa/appengine-gcs-blobstore-python

Comment: Google recommends cloud storage instead of Blobstore and there are some discussion and assumptions (search for blobstore) if blobstore will be further developed https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/blobstore/

Comment: @voscausa Did you experience this issue maybe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47703942/transformationerror-reasons-get-serving-url-images-api

Comment: No never. I can't help you with this.

Comment: You need to create a BlobStoreKey, but its just a reference to GCS. So nothing "unrecommended" its the only way if you want to use the Image API. I dont program in python but the approach looks correct. Whats the error?

Comment: Ah and i never got it to work locally.... just online.