# TransformationError Reasons get_serving_url / Images API

Tags: python, image, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm running into the following error using get_serving_url in order to serve images from my bucket.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
   return method(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 1087, in synctasklet_wrapper
   return taskletfunc(*args, **kwds).get_result()
 File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 1057, in tasklet_wrapper
   result = func(*args, **kwds)
 File "/base/data/home/apps/e~tileserve20171207t210519.406056180994857717/blob_upload.py", line 70, in post
   bf.put_async()
 File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 3473, in _put_async
   self._pre_put_hook()
 File "/base/data/home/apps/e~tileserve/20171207t210519.406056180994857717/blob_files.py", line 124, in _pre_put_hook
   print images.get_serving_url(None, filename='/gs' + '/tileserve.appspot.com/user2test4test4RGB20170927.tif')
 File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/images/__init__.py", line 1868, in get_serving_url
   return rpc.get_result()
 File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 613, in get_result
   return self.__get_result_hook(self)
 File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/images/__init__.py", line 1972, in get_serving_url_hook
   raise _ToImagesError(e, readable_blob_key)
 TransformationError
```

When I upload an image to my bucket then it works but when I create an image through processing which should be exposed through get_serving_url I get TransformationError.

I tried two variants for serving images:

```
test = blobstore.create_gs_key('/gs' + '/path2object')
images.get_serving_url(test, secure_url=True)

images.get_serving_url(None, filename='/gs' + '/' + <bucket name>+  '/'+ <object name>)
```

I also set the bucket object ACM permissions and the IAM App Engine app default service account permissions (storage admin). Both variants changed nothing but are important in order to access objects of a bucket.

Did somebody experience this issue ? What could be the error? I do not understand why it works when I upload an image but not for images which are generated through processing.

Comment: Usually `TransformationError` is returned by the images API. Can you show the full traceback?

Comment: Hi ..Yes I know but I did not find a solution and the reason for this error. I added the full traceback to my question

Comment: Can you show the code preceeding `blobstore.create_gs_key` which saves the transformed image in GCS?

Comment: I am processing satellite images with earth engine ..Earth Engine provides a API with an export2cloudstorage function. I can't set a header. Do you think this could be the problem ? I thought about implementing a function which reads the content in the bucket and write it backs with a header like options={b'x-goog-acl': b'public-read', b'cache-control': b'private, max-age=0, no-cache'})

Comment: Thank you so much for helping

Comment: @MichaEl I've come across the question now.  Can you either update the question or accept the solution with the update operations?

Answer (score 2):

The traceback suggests you may be trying to call `images.get_serving_url()` while an async operation may still be in progress.

If that op is actually saving the transformed image in GCS then it could explain the failure: `get_serving_url()` includes a check of the file being a valid image, which would fail with `TransformationError` if the file is not yet saved.

If so - you can fix the problem by either:

- switching to the sync version of saving the image
- waiting until saving the image completes (in case you have some other stuff to do in the meantime) - get the result of the sync call before invoking `get_serving_url()`
- repeatedly trying `get_serving_url()` while catching `TransformationError` until it no longer fails that way. This is a bit risky as it can end up in an infinite loop if `TransformationError` is raised for reasons other than simply saving the image being incomplete.

Comment: Yeah you are right there is a check of the file which leads to an error...that's strange because all images are written to gcs and ready to serve ... Maybe something what is wrong with the generated image format ...Do you know a working example where gcs content is exposed through get_serving_url ? all examples are based on a upload first. This already works in my case

Comment: Make sure the transformed file is *actually* saved before calling `get_serving_url()`.

Comment: @DanCornilescu what is the flag to write in sync mode?  My pattern is         write_retry_params = gcs.RetryParams(backoff_factor=1.1)
        gcs_file = gcs.open(filename,
                            'w',
                            content_type='image/%s' % file_type,
                            options={'x-goog-meta-user': identifier},
                            retry_params=write_retry_params)
        gcs_file.write(content)
        gcs_file.close()
        bkey = blobstore.create_gs_key('/gs%s' % filename)
        url = images.get_serving_url(bkey, secure_url=True)

Comment: @user1961. It's not a flag, it's the API call being made. In the original post it'd probably be something like `bf.put()` instead of `bf.put_async()`. Your write is sync.

Comment: @DanCornilescu Mayb it's different in my case.  I'm not writing to the datastore, I'm writing to the bucket in GCS via "gcs_file.write(content) and gcs_file.close()" where content is the image binary.  It works haphazardly so I thought it would be a sync issue.  But I presumed file.write() for GCS was sync.  Thanks for your time and attention.

Comment: @DanCornilescu it was not a sync issue in my case but rather related to the content.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not with the get_serving_url() method. It is how you are accessing the objects from google cloud storage bucket.

I switched the access control on my bucket from uniform to fine grained which fixed the problem for me.